# No load balancer created and static ip assigned to traefik ingress on GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, traefik, google-kubernetes-engine

When I set up an ingress controller to point to the traefik service, I expect load balancers to be created for that ingress controller on GKE in the same way a `LoadBalancer` service would. I could then point to the static ip created.

However, when I get my ingresses, there is no static IP assigned.

```
$ kubectl get ingresses -n kube-system
NAME              HOSTS                 ADDRESS   PORTS     AGE
traefik-ingress   traefik-ui.minikube             80        4m
```

**traefik-ingress.yml**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: traefik-ingress
  namespace: kube-system
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
spec:
  rules:
    - host: traefik-ui.minikube
      http:
        paths:
          - path: "/"
            backend:
              serviceName: traefik-ingress-service
              servicePort: 80
```

**traefik-deployment.yml**

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: traefik-ingress-controller
  namespace: kube-system
---
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: traefik-ingress-controller
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: traefik-ingress-lb
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: traefik-ingress-lb
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: traefik-ingress-lb
        name: traefik-ingress-lb
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: traefik-ingress-controller
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60
      containers:
        - image: traefik
          name: traefik-ingress-lb
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 80
            - name: admin
              containerPort: 8080
          args:
            - --api
            - --kubernetes
            - --logLevel=INFO
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: traefik-ingress-service
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  selector:
    k8s-app: traefik-ingress-lb
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      name: web
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      name: admin
  type: NodePort
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are creating a `Service` object for the traefik deployment, but you have used the `NodePort` type, which is only accesible from inside the cluster. If you want Kubernetes to create a LoadBalancer for a `Service`, you need to specify the type `LoadBalancer` in your service, so your traefik `Service` would look like

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: traefik-ingress-service
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  selector:
    k8s-app: traefik-ingress-lb
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      name: web
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      name: admin
  type: LoadBalancer
```

This will talk to the GKE API and create a LoadBalancer with an IP for you.

Comment: yeap so I didn't really understand the relationship between the service and ingress.